# Rotating problems while animating

Tags: animation

For some reason, whenever I change the x-axis, the object turns on the z-axis [image]

[image]

Any Ideas on what's causing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try applying transforms? Your scale is not 1. Select your mesh and press Ctrl - A, apply rotation and scale